# How to display downloaded image into alert dialog correctly not based on the size?

Tags: android, imageview, android-volley, android-alertdialog

what I am trying to do is show some images I download from an url. I managed to download and show the images, but I can not figure out how to show the correctly based on the size, by size I mean hight and width not kb.

I am using volley to download the images. The alert dialog is shown after a click within a fragment view.

This is the layout

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProduct"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is how I show the alert dialog

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View imageDialog = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_product_image, null);
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(imageDialog);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    //dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    ImageView imgImage = imageDialog.findViewById(R.id.imgProduct);

    String url = product.urlImage.replaceAll("\\s+","");

    ImageRequest imgRequest = new ImageRequest(url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
            imgImage.setImageBitmap(response);
            imgImage.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in));
        }
    }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            imgImage.setImageResource(RES_ERROR);
            Toast.makeText(context, VolleyManager.getInstance(context)
                    .checkError(error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    imgRequest.setTag(CANCELABLE_REQUEST_TAG);
    VolleyManager.getInstance(context).getRequestQ().add(imgRequest);

    // Set your image

    dialog.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Any help or suggestions would be great, thanks

Comment: why don't you use glide or Picasso ?

Comment: thansk for the reply. I´m sorry, but what would be the difference? do not know much of either of those

Comment: In my opinion it's way easier and faster to implement in your case , check any of them it's only 3 lines of code , also you can specify the dimensions you need in the view itself on `layout_width` and `layout_height` then choose scale type

Comment: I will check them out, thanks. But what I am trying to acomplish is show tham dinamically and not give the image a fix size, altough the alert dialog is ment to be fixed size

Comment: You will need to keep the aspect ratio of the image on the device it is being displayed. With "centerCrop" scale type, the image will be scaled uniformly to maintain aspect ratio. This means image will take size taken by the layout which may not be the exact aspect ratio of the original image.  So, the best way to show the image as the original one is by setting the width to match_parent and compute the height  as mentioned here https://www.ryadel.com/en/android-proportionally-stretch-imageview-fit-whole-screen-width-maintaining-aspect-ratio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment above, use Piccaso. Try this and modify from "ImageView imgImage = imageDialog.findViewById(R.id.imgProduct);"

```
Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                imgImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                doFoo();
            }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            imgImage.setImageDrawable(errorDrawable);
            Toast.makeText(context, "download failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            doBar();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            imgImage.setImageDrawable(placeHolderDrawable);
        }
    };

    //this will help us to avoid the Target being gc'd
    imgImage.setTag(target);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(RES_PLACEHOLDER)
            .error(RES_ERROR)
            .resize(400, 400)
            .into(target);

    // Set your image

    dialog.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

and then used dummy functions

```
private void doFoo() {
    //dummy
}
private void doBar() {
    //dummy
}
```